# Play json: parse array of arrays of longs?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have this json structure:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "values": [
        [
          1570054140892,
          1
        ],
        [
          1570208848841,
          1
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to parse it in Scala using play-json library with this code:

```
val results: Option[JsValue] = (json \ "results") match {
  case JsDefined(value: JsValue) => Some(value)
  case JsUndefined() => None
}

val valueReads: Reads[List[List[Long]]] = (JsPath \ "values").read[List[List[Long]]]
val parsed = results.flatMap{ r =>

r.validate[List[List[Long]]](valueReads) match {
    case s: JsSuccess[List[List[Long]]] => Some(s)
    case _: JsError => None
  }}
println("parsed: " + parsed)
```

It prints:

> parsed: None

Why my code doesn't work and how to parse this json correctly with play-json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `r` inside your `flatMap` is a `JsArray` itself that contains only one object. This inner object is the one you are looking for.

So you can make your code work by:

```
val parsed = results.flatMap{ r =>

r.as[JsArray].value.head.validate[List[List[Long]]](valueReads) match {
  case s: JsSuccess[List[List[Long]]] => Some(s)
  case _: JsError => None
}}

parsed: Some(JsSuccess(List(List(1570054140892, 1), List(1570208848841, 1)),/values))
```

Or you can use a case class like this:

```
case class LongList(values : List[List[Long]])
case class Parent(results : List[LongList])

implicit val cnv = Json.format[LongList]
implicit val cnv2 = Json.format[Parent]
val parsed = json.as[Parent]
println(parsed)
```

ouputs:

```
Parent(List(LongList(List(List(1570054140892, 1), List(1570208848841, 1)))))
```